# Should certificates and fastlane files be committed to git in an XCode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fastlane

I have created a provisioning profile to deploy an iOS app to the test flight using fastlane.

Following is the list of files that I have added to .gitignore

- fastlane/report.xml
- fastlane/Preview.html
- fastlane/screenshots
- fastlane/test_output
- fastlane/README.md

Should I also be adding the following files to .gitignore?

- Files in the folder /certificates
- fastlane/Appfile
- fastlane/Fastfile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use the `testflight` action, but I do use fastlane, so I know that you absolutely do want to add:

- fastlane/Fastfile
- fastlane/Appfile

The Fastfile contains the logic for your lane itself.

I also imagine that you'll want to add your certificates to your repo if you want to run your fastlane from other machines.

Comment: In my opinion, if `match` is used, certificates should not be stored twice.

Comment: Sounds smart. If match is used, no need to store in git. We don't use match in-house for various reasons.

Comment: What about `Gemfile`, `Gemfile.lock`, `.Gemfile`?

Comment: The first two, yes. I am unfamiliar with .Gemfile